# How to configure word2vec to not use negative-sampling?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, word2vec

I want to compare word embeddings trained with and without negative sampling.
I used google word2vec tool.
I set the parameters negative=-1. I assume this means we don't use negative sampling.
But, it seems using negative=25 is slower than negative=-1, which makes me wonder does negative=-1 really mean not using negative sampling?

Any one familiar with word2vec c implementation can help me?
How can I train a model without negative sampling using word2vec tool?

Answer (score 2):

`negative=0` means no negative-sampling, in both the original word2vec.c tool, and some things modeled after it (like Python gensim).

If not using negative-sampling, you'd have to enable hierarchical-softmax, the alternative method of generating back-propagatable prediction errors. It is enabled by `hs=1`.

Note negative sampling is the usual default, and often preferred for large-datasets/large-vocabularies, as its training-performance doesn't become slower with a large vocabulary.

Comment: If I set negative=0 and hs=0, does this mean do not use negative-sampling and hierarchical-softmax, just go through all the vocabulary to calculate the errors? Or I can not set both of them to be 0?

Comment: Try it. You'll either get an error, or really fast training that performs really poorly in evaluations (because it leaves vectors in random initial locations). One or the other mode is absolutely necessary. (Original word2vec.c also allowed enabling both, which was a bit like having 2 models, with the same 'input' word-vectors, but two-difference output layers, each being alternately evaluated/backpropagated to correct the same inputs – so as slow as both combined.)

Comment: Yeah, I tried to set both of them to be 0. The result is extremely bad just like you said. I see what's going on. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Also tried it out accidentally and got really bad results. I currently try to use comparably high values of "negative" in order to see if that improves the embedding. I would have expected that disabling negative sampling by setting negative=0 to update all weights and therefor give a more meaningful embedding, but strangely it does not happen. What exactly does the algorithm do when you disable negative sampling and not enabling hs? Is backpropagation only applied to the "positive" output nodes?

Comment: No training happens if `hs=0, negative=0`, because neither method of evaluating the neural network's outputs & back-propagating improvements is enabled. It's a nonsense setting resulting in no training. (If you're watching logs/output, I think you'll see a warning.)